# Calculate the stress tensor on the surface of a tube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

I am studying engineering and I was doing some preparation for the exam but stumbled accross the following problem:

[image]

I would know how to solve task 2-4 but I am stuck at task 1.
I do have multiple questions:

1. Why is the spiral form important?
2. If I want to calculate the stress tensor, would I need to reduce the forces into my point x where I want to  calculate the stress-tensor?
3. Now If I reduce the forces to point x, how do i get to the entries in the tensor? Because I would have 9 entries and only 1 resulting force + 1 moment

I am not asking anyone here to do my homework, it is just a general question on the step of calculating a stress tensor.

Hope somebody could help me with this one :)

Comment: (1). It's not important for Q #1. It's important for Q#4. (2) Yes, but the answer shouldn't depend on the specific point in the cylinder for this problem. (3) You're saying that you can't determine a stress tensor unless you're given 9 forces or moments?

Comment: Well yeah, I just do not understand the step from the force/moment in point x to get to the tesnor

Comment: In this situation, the state of stress is homogeneous.  Suppose the moment M were not present but the force F is; would you know how to determine the components of the stress tensor for this situation?  Suppose that the force F were not present but the moment M is; would you know how to determine the components of the stress tensor for this situation?